# .NET Core 3.1 windows service timeout on startup

Tags: .net, windows-services

We have a .NET Core 3.1 Windows Service that, sporadically, gets a timeout while starting. The service hits the 30 seconds windows service default timeout and doesn't start anymore but manually.

This is the code that creates and starts the service:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var logger = LogHelper.GetLogger();

        try
        {
            logger.Info($"Starting {Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName} Branch: {ThisAssembly.Git.Branch} Commit: {ThisAssembly.Git.Commit}");

            var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                        {
                            webBuilder
                            //.UseIISIntegration()
                            .UseStartup<Startup>();
                        })
                        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                        {
                            logging.ClearProviders();
                            logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
                        })
                        .UseNLog()
                        .UseWindowsService()
                        .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //NLog: catch setup errors
            logger.Error(exception, "Stopped program because of exception");
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
            NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
        }
    }
```

Obviously, in most of the installation the service is starting correctly within a reasonable amount of time. The issue mostly happens when a "not-very-performing-server" is being restarted.

Has anyone any clue?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe missing hosting lifetime messages: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Hosting-Lifetime-Startup-Messages

Comment: Messages from hosting lifetime logging are written correctly. Anyways, it's not an usual behavior not to start within 30 seconds, but it happens randomly.

Comment: I failed to find old implementation of WindowsServiceLifetime. But what I can tell you is that in .NET Core 5 hosted services start & runnung is implemented in a separate thread. So you won't experience this issue. This has some drawbacks (like for example your service is reported started but in reality it's still starting)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Anyways we are using dotnet 6.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and derive from [WindowsServiceLifetime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices) that derives from the old friend [ServiceBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase) that has the protected method `RequestAdditionalTime`.

Maybe something like this:

```
builder.UseWindowsService(o => o.ServiceName = sn);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHostLifetime, AdditionalTimeLifetime>();
```

```cs
    class AdditionalTimeLifetime : WindowsServiceLifetime
    {
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            base.OnStart(args);
    
            RequestAdditionalTime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
        }
    }
```

See also: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/75276

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service